# Highlighting parts of objects throughout animation

Tags: animation, video

I'm making a technical animation to supplement a training document for a lab procedure.

I'd like to annotate the video by highlighting objects (or parts of objects) to draw attention to specific details. There wouldn't be any motion throughout the animation, so motion tracking wouldn't be an issue.

For example:

[image]
[image]

How can this be achieved within blender?

Comment: Good points, thanks! As for built-in vs post-processing, I'm not sure. Whichever way makes more sense, I suppose. I find my animation projects are messy and difficult to navigate as it is, so adding the annotations would just make matters worse. I'd be open to built-in, if that's what makes the most sense.

Comment: Unrelated: You seen Reynante Martinez's [brain shader?](http://www.blendernation.com/headers/cycles-material-studies-volume-11/) it may be worth looking into. if that's a brain... cause I think it is...

Comment: @RadishoftheOpera yeah, I love it! Reynante is a wizard :) When I try to recreate materials like that, it usually just leaves me frustrated that I can't come even close :P So I tend to go for simple stuff that looks fine, rather than botching an attempt at amazing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can animate the material colours as others have suggested you can also composite the change [using masks](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor).

Masks can be created in the Movie Editor for existing videos or in the UV/Image Editor if you just want to align a mask to the current render result or image. If your items were moving then you could animate the mask in the Movie Editor to follow the items, you can even parent them to motion tracked points instead of manually positioning each frame.

[image]

The bonus with compositing is that if you have already rendered the video or want to adjust an existing video it is much quicker than re-rendering the whole animation.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply animate the colour of the material of your object, maybe with the emission value also.
Create copies of the material, one for every part to be highlighted, then animate the colour and the emission value.

Comment: To clarify: it is possible for one mesh to have multiple materials, and you assign those materials to the appropriate polygons.

Answer (score 1):

You can keyframe colors for a shader by tapping <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering the mouse cursor over the color field.  This works for most, if not all, value fields in various areas of Blender.

Once you add a keyframe, the color box will have a yellow border.  Now when you move the Timeline slider, the outline will turn green to indicate that a keyframe has not yet been set for this new position.  You can change the color and then press <kbd>i</kbd> again while hovering over the new color to set the color for that frame.

[image]